# Accessing Azure File Share from Windows Web App

Tags: mount, azure-web-apps

I have a Windows Azure Web App that uploads files to a directory called 'CallRecordings' in the website root.

I wish to use a virtual directory pointing to an Azure file share. I have mounted the file share from the Azure portal and it appears at D:\mounts\callrecordings.

My question is how do I map this to a virtual directory so that the App cab use it? The portal only allows \sites mappings.

My test app is running on the F1 tier, should I use a different tier? I'm hoping to do this using configuration so that I don't have to change the App.

Any advice is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? I'm trying the exact same option, but adding a virtual path outside site\ seems impossible

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/523329)

Comment: I've got this on the back burner but it's still an issue